# Crystal Reports for VS2012 - VS2013 - VS2015 - VS2017 - VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have installed VS2012 Ultimate on a fresh PC. I tried adding the Crystal Reports file in my project but there is no crystal report .crt Item avaliable into Add New Item menu of the VS2012

Is there a version for VS2012? or do I have to install an extra setup file for crystal reports which is redundant since I already have VS2012 installed.

Comment: CR SP5 that supports VS2012, Win8 and SQL 2012 fully released
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 108, accepted):

### Here it is! - SP 25 works on Visual Studio 2019, SP 21 on Visual Studio 2017

SAP released **SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio**

### [You can get it here](http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/) (click "Installation package for Visual Studio IDE")

> To integrate “SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio” you must **run the Install Executable**. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only.

> New In SP25 Release
>
> Visual Studio 2019, Addressed incidents, Win10 1809, Security update

Comment: I have deployed my web application on IIS 8 Express build in VS2012 .NET Framework 4.5. Crytal reports are not displaying anything but localy when i run my project through VS2012 it display data in browser. i have copy CrystalReportViewer13 folder in my website root folder but facing the same issue, anyone can guide me regarding this issue?

Comment: It seems pretty insecure that an SO link points directly to an exe. Anyone could edit this answer to download a virus and infect companies everywhere. People with only 2k rep can edit without reviewers, and even with reviewers, you can make a bus.inessobjects.com link and make a few other relevant changes to the answer.

Comment: ***latest*** `Support Pack 18 (v.13.0.18.2192)`  _“SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio” can be used with Visual Studio 2010 to 2015_ https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Answer (score 5):

[This post is right from SAP on Sep 20, 2012](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/09/20/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio--2012-support-update).

In short, they are still working on a release of Crystal Reports that will support VS2012 (including support for Windows 8)  It will come in the form of a service pack release that updates the version currently supporting VS2010.  At that time they will drop 2010/2012 from the name and simply call it Crystal Reports Developer.

If you want to download that version you can find it [here](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp).

Further, service packs etc. when released can be found [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824).

---

I would also add that I am currently using Visual Studio 2012.  As long as you don't edit existing reports they continue to compile and work fine.  Even on Windows 8.  When I need to modify a report I can still open the project with VS2010, do my work, save my changes, and then switch back to 2012.  It's a little bit of a pain but the ability for VS2010 and VS2012 to co-exist is nice in this regard.  I'm also using TFS2012 and so far it hasn't had a problem with me modifying files in 2010 on a "2012" solution.

Comment: According to the first link from SAP it should arrive 4th quarter 2012.  So up to 1.5 months to go.  Maybe more people should sign up and show interest in the [thread](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/09/20/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio--2012-support-update) (by liking and commenting) to prod them a bit more?

Comment: Actually the [page](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2012/09/20/sap-crystal-reports-developer-version-for-microsoft-visual-studio--2012-support-update) used to say 4th quarter 2012, but now it says 'late 1st quarter 2013'.

Answer (score 1):

There is also someone who `managed to modify CR for VS.NET 2010 to install on 2012, using MS ORCA` in this thread: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3235515 .  I couldn't get it to work myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

"SP25 work on Visual Studio 2019" is an exaggeration. It is extremely unreliable and should be avoided at all costs. I currently have to maintain a second development environment with V2015 for report development.