# Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2012 - Where's the integration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2012

I want to create some reports with 'crystal report' to my ASP.NET MVC Application.
So I've downloaded SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - 2012' on http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012/14384613#14384613)

But where is the 'Add new Crystal Report' button?
Do I need any plugin to create new Crystal Reports? Where's the featured VS2012 integration??

Thanks

Comment: VS2012 removed and installed again; fixed.