# How to use ReportViewer in VS 2012 Express from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, report, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for the application and MYSQL for the database.

The problem is I have is to create a report using ReportViewer (crystal report didn't support VS 2012 yet) but using a MYSQL database. And I didn't have any experience using ReportViewer

1. Is there any way to insert a Dataset to .rdlc document without using Wizard, or can I create a datasource from the Wizard that are linked to my MYSQL database?
2. Is there any other available solution to generate a report from VS 2012?

**EDIT**

So the Crystal Report for VS2012 have been launched at 14 January this year. Here is the [link to the Crystal Report discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012). I think I'll using crystal report for the reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why didn't u follow the wizard?

**PREREQUIRED:** [MySQL Connector for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

New DataSet -> New... -> Database -> DataSet -> New Connection -> select "MySQL Database"

Now you have to select the location of your mysql server, username/password ecc...

Comment: why everytime I adding a new dataset, there is a popup saying "Could not get type information for "Project.projectDataSet