# Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2012

I am currently migrating some VS 2005 projects to VS 2012.

All of them compiled fine, but when I tried to run it, I got a crystal report error:

> Error 1   Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

VS 2005 has built in support for crystal reports, but VS 2012 doesn't seem to have that. I googled and found out that there is a new update available from Crystal reports to work with VS 2012, but the link seems dead (http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074)

Can Anybody show me the way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012