# Does using Crystal Reports in myapp require installation on other pc?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have created my app which uses Crystal reports will the user of another pc require Crystal Report installation on his pc to use myapp on his own pc

Answer (score 0):

From my experience they will need to have the crystal reports runtime version that you used in you app. Most of the time it is included when you package the app up. If not it is a small download and is fairly simple to install.

Comment: well I did give my app to my professor who had only ms access and dotnet 4.0 installed and it still worked

Answer (score 0):

To use your app it is not required, it is sufficient to have crystal report runtime. But to use your report template they certainly need the crystal report installtion.
Visual studio 2008 has built in support to visualize your report template using it they can also edit. Afterwards realeases requires patch to visualize the report template.

Go through the following link to work with visual studio 2010 [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual)

Go through the following link to work with visual studio 2012,2013 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695563/crystal-reports-for-vs2012-vs2013)